# Discord (the desktop program), says I need to update the app in order to verify the phone number. Is there an option in Discord to update it?

Tags: discord

Discord (the desktop program), says I need to update the app in order to verify the phone number.

Is there an option in Discord to update it?

I suppose I could try uninstalling and reinstalling discord..

[image]

**added**

this is when trying to join a particular group/chat rooms/"discord servers". I can still communicate in the other groups/chat rooms/"discord servers".

Comment: Are you trying to bypass verifying your phone number (which is tied to your account) or update the application itself.  I have gone weeks without installing Discord updates, so I suspect, the need to verify your phone connected to your account is **account specific**  [Looking into this message, seems to suggest, that Discord support and Discord alone can release your account from this current state.  Uninstalling Discord will only result in, you reinstalling the application, and being stuck on the same step in 5 minutes.](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/8mhzax/)

Comment: i think uninstalling is safe 'cos data is in the discord account profile.. you could go to the discord.com interface and verify it there as that interface would be up to date.. could possibly do it from another computer where you install it fresh but website interface is easiest.

Comment: AT Ramhound maybe the person that set up that "room"/"discord server", requested telephone number verification. Normally it doesn't ask me.

Comment: Except I almost certain that a phone is a  requirement for a Discord account.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe I managed to set one up without a phone number then! (and it came back to get one off me!)

Comment: You will have to contact Discord support more than likely to solve this problem.

Comment: see my first comment to this question and it states a workaround

Comment: [This](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4415274867351-Locked-out-of-Account) and [this](https://support.discord.com/hc/th/community/posts/360051715194-Something-s-Going-on-here-Phone-verification-?page=5) should help your situation.

Comment: AT Ramhound  easiest thing for now is just to verify it through the website. (note that my scenario isn't the same as those people)